# Deploying a java play application

Tags: java, linux, playframework-2.0

I created a small play application and generated the dist files using "play dist"

After running the "start" script, the application works locally, but when I try to unzip the file generated on a server or giving it to other colleagues, the output says :

```
./start
Play server process ID is 13585
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

When i access the server on port 9000 (`http://correct-server-url-or-ip:9000`) , the browser shows that the page is loading but it never loads.

If I kill the process on the server, the browser immediately shows an error.

I am not sure why it works on my machine but doesn't deploy on other machines with similar configurations.

Did anyone have a problem like that? or know how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: If its a web application, make sure to generate the war file properly and make sure your war contains all the third party libraries in *WEB-INF/lib* folder and you have no direct dependencies on the application server libraries as well.

Comment: Might be a internal firewall or anti virus software blocking it. Is it windows?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am still not sure how i can create a war file with play 2.1

Comment: @AdamGent My machine is macos (app works on that), my colleague's machine is macos as well (app doesn't work there), server os is Cent os (doesn't work there). The same output in the console is generated on all three machines. Assuming it is firewall, why wouldn't it work on my colleague's machine, we tried accessing http://localhost:9000 ?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: No, please, you didn't read the question properly. Your advice doesn't apply. WaelAwada: Don't try the war thing. Does the console or the log file say anything? Does your application access a database that you haven#t started on the target computer? (Maybe you didn't wait enough for that or your timeout is too long.)

Comment: @Carsten The application doesn't have a database, it simply has few controllers that capture input from the views, and a Webservices SOAP client that connects to a webservice and displays its output.

Comment: @Carsten just placed my point of view for common Java web applications. Also, looks like the problem is in the server side, not from the application.

Comment: @WaelAwada Maybe reaching the webservice is the problem.

Comment: @Carsten the webservice is on the same machine as the server and the server has all the ports open in our local intranet. I am just not sure if play needs any special libraries or I am missing something .. I just moved the zip file to the server, unzipped and ran start.